# Livewire: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object generating code from foreach

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Livewire and I encounter an error which origin I don't know.

I made a page with a list of simple objects (id, name, and description). The page has a list of all the items available and I want to click on that list to view the item properties or a button to delete the item.

That list is made with this foreach:

```
@foreach($listaTareas as $t)
  <div class="data col-12" wire:click="show({{ $t->id }})">
    <label>{{ $t->nombre }}</label>
    <label class="hint">ID: {{ $t->id }}</label>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" wire:click="delete({{ $t->id }})"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

Which renders perfectly

[List rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdtda.png)

However, clicking on any div or in the trash can button results in error **Trying to get property 'id' of non-object** pointing at *<div class="data col-12" wire:click="show({{ $t->id }})">*.

If I delete the *show* and *delete* attributes (and modify the livewire component consequentely) leaving something like this:

```
@foreach($listaTareas as $t)
  <div class="data col-12" wire:click="show">
    <label>{{ $t->nombre }}</label>
    <label class="hint">ID: {{ $t->id }}</label>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" wire:click="delete"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

I still get the same error, this time pointing at **<label>{{ $t->nombre }}</label>**, so crearly there is something obvious I'm doing incredibly wrong. I have heard about the wire:key attribute but I don't know how to use it for my purposes.

**All the code:**

**Livewire view**

```
<div class="row align-items-start">
    <!-- Sección de la lista de tareas -->
    <div class="col-5">
        <div id="listado" class="contenedor-data">

            <div id="add">
                <label for="btnadd" class="info">Puedes añadir una tarea con este botón...</label>
                <button id="btnadd" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" wire:click="create">Añadir</button>
            </div>

            @foreach($listaTareas as $t)
                <div class="data col-12" wire:click="show({{ $t->id }})">
                    <label>{{ $t->nombre }}</label>
                    <label class="hint">ID: {{ $t->id }}</label>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" wire:click="delete({{ $t->id }})"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        
            <div id="coletilla">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#add" role="button">&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>&nbsp;</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Sección del desglose de tareas -->
    <div class="col-7">
        <div id="desglose" class="contenedor-data">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nombre">Tarea:</label>
                <label id="id_tarea" class="hint">{{ $tid }}</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre de la tarea" wire:model="nombre">
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="descripcion">Descripción</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="descripcion" aria-describedby="hint" wire:model="descripcion"></textarea>
                <small id="hint" class="form-text text-muted">Aquí va la descripción de la tarea.</small>
            </div>
            
            <div>
                <button id="btnadd" type="button" class="btn btn-success" wire:click="create">Añadir</button>
                <button id="btnmod" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Modificar</button>
                <button id="btndel" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Livewire Component**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Tarea;

class Index extends Component
{

    // Atributos de tareas
    public $tid;
    public $nombre;
    public $descripcion;

    // Listado tareas
    public $listaTareas = array();

    public function create() {
        $tarea = new Tarea;

        $tarea->nombre = $this->nombre;
        $tarea->descripcion = $this->descripcion;

        if ($tarea->save()) {
            $this->tid = 'ID: '.$tarea->id;
        }

    }

    public function show($id) {
        /* Just to try if it works */
        $this->descripcion = "Show $id";
    }

    public function delete() {
        /* Just to try if it works */
        $this->descripcion = "Delete $id";
    }

    private function rellenarTareas() {
        $tareas = Tarea::get();

        foreach($tareas as $tarea) {
            $this->listaTareas[] = $tarea;
        }
    }

    public function mount()
    {
        // Rellenamos la lista con las tareas que ya existen
        $this->rellenarTareas();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.index');
    }
}
```

Comment: `listaTareas` has at least (1) element in the array that is not an object which is resulting in this error. Can you dump `listaTareas` and see it's value?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Yes, here is the dump:
`array:3 [▼
  0 => App\Models\Tarea {#365 ▶}
  1 => App\Models\Tarea {#380 ▶}
  2 => App\Models\Tarea {#381 ▶}
]`

What is bugging me is there is no error with listaTareas loading de page, the `foreach` works fine. The error comes when click on an element of the list. What I'm trying to do is use the `show` and `delete` just as a normal functions, but even if I remove the id parameter from them the error still happens, pointing at `$t->nombre`, so I have no idea the reason this is happening

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem. It was as simple as tricky. In `rellenarTareas()`, called by `mount()`, I was getting the **Tarea** objects from the database and inserting them into an array

```
private function rellenarTareas() {
    $tareas = Tarea::get();

    foreach($tareas as $tarea) {
        $this->listaTareas[] = $tarea;
    }
}
```

Debugging the data with `dd()` showed this:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => App\Models\Tarea {#365 ▶}
  1 => App\Models\Tarea {#367 ▶}
  2 => App\Models\Tarea {#381 ▶}
]
```

I changed the way the array `$listaTareas` was being filled by directly storing the `Tareas::get()` into `$listaTareas` (btw I renamed `$listaTareas` to `$tareas`):

```
private function rellenarTareas() {
    $this->tareas = Tarea::get();
}
```

Debugging the data with `dd()` showed this:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#364 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => App\Models\Tarea {#365 ▶}
    1 => App\Models\Tarea {#367 ▶}
    2 => App\Models\Tarea {#381 ▶}
  ]
}
```

I have no idea why this solved the issue, but it does. I hope this helps to any newbie like me in Livewire or Laravel.